# A piping-hot bowl of new Moderator Pro Tempore

Tags: discussion, moderators

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that a new member has stepped up and generously volunteered his time to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: tim.plunkett]

...joins [the existing pro tem mods](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97/moderator-pro-tem-announcement). We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

Comment: Welcome tim, looking forward to getting some extra help.

Comment: Welcome tim, nice to see you around :)